Retro PC: How to Install Windows XP to SSD Using PATA to SATA Adapter On ICH1 Through ICH6
I purchased a PATA to SATA adapter with a JM20330 chip to use with a cheap SSD on a retro PC (Celeron 1.2GHz on socket 370 with ICH2 chipset) running Windows XP. I booted the Windows XP installer CD and it could not detect the drive, but the system BIOS detects the drive just fine. So I installed Windows XP to a PATA drive I had. I used a Service Pack 2 version of XP Home. Once booted to the desktop the SSD was still not detected. I had to install Service Pack 3 and the Intel Application Accelerator version for my motherboard. After that the SSD was visible to Windows XP installed to the PATA drive.
In order to make a bootable Windows XP installer CD to install onto the SSD I tried extracting the IAA driver used for the PATA controller from the PATA installation using DriverExtractor. Then I used nlite with a Windows XP Home SP3 CD and added the drivers. Unfortunately, the installer still couldn't see the SSD.
Is there anything I can do to get the Windows XP installer to see this SSD using this PATA to SATA adpater so that I can install to and boot from the SSD?

If the SSD was visible to XP SP3 what exactly is your question

@Ramhound I want to use the SSD as a boot drive. So I would need to be able to install to it.

As is tradition, once I asked the question I found an answer myself.
I downloaded the Intel Application Accelerator installer (infinst-autol.zip) from https://theretroweb.com/motherboards/s/lite-on-tr100#driver. Once downloaded I used 7zip to extract the files. Then I launched a command prompt with admin privileges and navigated to the folder where I extracted the files and ran the following command:
setup -a -p c:\tempfolder

I then added the XP drivers within that folder to a Windows XP Home SP3 installer CD using nlite and the installer was finally able to see the SSD and install Windows XP.
This driver download should work for any retro motherboard using an ICH1 through ICH6 chipset.
